# Rails 4 - where to store temporarily files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, tmp

I am generating txt/pdf documents, saving them (currently) in the `/tmp` directory, uploading them to Amazon S3 and then removing them from the `/tmp` directory.

The problem is that when I deploy some new code while a new file being currently generated, the process of generating is interrupted, because the file is removed from the `/tmp` directory.

Where is the best to store temporary documents within the Rails system?

Answer (score 1):

The common directory for this is the `tmp` directly, like you mention.

To get around issues of the tmp directory being "dereferenced" during a deployment, you can symlink the `tmp` directory to a shared directory that doesn't get reset on each deploy. The same concept applies to logs and other shared config.

So your directory structure might look something like this:

- `www/`

  - `appname/`

    - `current/`
    - `releases/`
    - `shared/`

      - `tmp/`
      - `config/`
      - `pids/`
      - `log/`